# javascript: will window.location make any warnings?

Tags: javascript, redirect, window

If I use `window.location = "";` to redirect a user, will any browsers give the user a warning message (since the page is redirecting without the user's consent)?

Should I use `window.location = ""` or `window.location.href = ""`?

Comment: About all I can think of is if you're redirecting from a secure SSL page to an insecure one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You will not get any warning (like you do if you close the window). And I have never seen any difference in location and location.href, but I use the last :)

Answer (score 2):

No you can redirect the window location on your own. The only similarly related thing you can't do automatically is click a link for the user with an event.

You might be thinking of this type of notice:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "Are you sure you want to navigate away?";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK window.location and window.location.href *should* be pretty much eqivalent.

It's been a while since I've used it, but I don't remember ever seeing a prompt before leaving the page. Most of the time when I have been prompted it's been because I explicitly put a confirmation in, such as when clicking a link to delete something.

Answer (score 1):

Setting window.location shouldn't cause any issues with redirection. However, if there is a hash, then some browsers may deal with it differently.

From the MDN spec:

> Note: The example above works in situations where window.location.hash does not need to be retained. However, in Gecko-based browsers, setting window.location.pathname in this manner will erase any information in window.location.hash, whereas in WebKit (and possibly other browsers), setting the pathname will not alter the the hash. If you need to change pathname but keep the hash as is, use the replace() method instead, which should work consistently across browsers.

There shouldn't be any difference between `location` and `location.href` since whenever a property of the location object is modified, a document will be loaded using the URL as if window.location.assign() had been called with the modified URL.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location